# Patch 7405 not applying because patch was detected

Tags: magento-1.8, patches

**Magento Version:** *1.8.1.0*

**Previous Patches Applied:** *1533, 5344, 5994, 6385, 6482, 6788, 4755*

I am working on applying the patch 7405 v1, but I receive these errors. When looking through the patch file and the files they are patching I noticed that the patch was applied to some of the files but not others.

**What I'm trying to figure out is:**

1. Why would there only be a portion of the patch applied and not the entire patch? Note: I tried running the patch multiple times.
2. How can I revert back to a previous state before applying this patch?

**What I see when attempting to apply patch:**

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
    ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.


    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php.rej
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php.rej
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
    Hunk #1 succeeded at 146 (offset 9 lines).

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml.rej
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    4 out of 4 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml

    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml

    patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml

    patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml

    patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

    patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php`
```